# Connect OCR API to gsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I would appreciate some help with the following

I am trying to connect with an html form the upload of a PDF document to an OCR service through an API, this is the code

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("formulario");
}


function procesForm(form) {

   console.log(form);

  var archivo = form.file;
  

  if (archivo != null) {

var bytes = Utilities.newBlob(archivo).getBytes();

var url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4";
var apiKey = "key";
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
};
var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "headers": headers,
  "payload": bytes
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

var parsedData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

var hojaDatos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
hojaDatos.appendRow([parsedData.document]);


  }
}
```

and here the form with which I upload the document

```
    <html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        google.script.run.procesarFormulario(form);
        
        form.reset();
      });

    </script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

The error that the console throws me is the following:

> Uncaught  at procesForm (Código:17)

I can't get the document to pass to the script so it can be sent to the server

Comment: First, I have to apologize for my poor experience. Unfortunately, I have no information about the API you want to use. So, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the official document of your endpoint of `https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Although I have no information about the API you want to use, I proposed a modified script by supposing that your script for requesting the API is correct. Please confirm it. If your request was not correct for using your API, I apologize.

Comment: excellent as always Tanaike, if you have solved my problem with your explanation of each step, you make me think and I learn, I thank you, you are a great value for the entire community and for those who are learning like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have no information about the API (`https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4`) you want to use. So, this is just my guess. And, I modified your showing script by supposing that your script for requesting the API is correct. Please be careful about this.

#### Modification points:

- In your Javascript side, `google.script.run.procesarFormulario(form);` is used. But, in your Google Apps Script side, `procesarFormulario` is not used. But, you say `Uncaught  at procesForm (Código:17)`. So, I'm worried that your tested script might be different from your showing script. So, in this answer, I suppose that `google.script.run.procesarFormulario(form);` might be `google.script.run.procesForm(form);`.
- With your showing HTML and Javascript, when `google.script.run.procesForm(form);` is run, `var archivo = form.file;` is a Blob. But, you use `var bytes = Utilities.newBlob(archivo).getBytes();`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
- And also, `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. By this, in the case of your showing script, after `google.script.run.procesarFormulario(form);` is run, `form.reset();` is run before `procesarFormulario` was finished. By this, the data might not be able to be correctly sent to the Google Apps Script side. I think that this is another issue in your script.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("formulario");
}

function procesForm(form) {
  var archivo = form.file;
  if (archivo != null) {
    var bytes = archivo.getBytes();

    var url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4";
    var apiKey = "key";
    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    };
    var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "headers": headers,
      "payload": bytes
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var hojaDatos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    hojaDatos.appendRow([parsedData.document]);
  }
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => form.reset()).procesForm(form);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- By the above modification, `var bytes = archivo.getBytes();` has the correct byte array of the uploaded file. But, as I have already mentioned at the top of my answer, I have no information about the API (`https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4`) you want to use. So, I suppose that your script of the request for the API is correct. Please be careful about this.
- If you tested this modified script and an error occurs at the request, in that case, it is considered that your script for requesting the API might not be correct. In that case, it is required to know the detailed specification of the API you want to use. Because I have no information about the API. Please be careful about this.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- This is also just my guess. If your script for requesting the API is not correct, please test the following modification. But, I have no information about the API you want to use. So, if this modified script was not useful, please provide the official document of the API `https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4`.

  ```js
  function procesForm(form) {
    var archivo = form.file;
    if (archivo != null) {
      var url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/parsing/parsers/TypeInvoiceV4";
      var apiKey = "key";
      var headers = { "Authorization": "Token " + apiKey };
      var options = { "method": "post", "headers": headers, "payload": { document: archivo } };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      var hojaDatos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      hojaDatos.appendRow([parsedData.document]);
    }
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: excellent as always Tanaike, if you have solved my problem with your explanation of each step, you make me think and I learn, I thank you, you are a great value for the entire community and for those who are learning like me

Comment: @Fabrisimo Thank you for replying and for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.